# Что такое явное указание аргумента типа?

Tags: java

Гуглил что это, но конкретного определения нету, хотя в целом понятно. Но как можно ответить на собеседовании и какие примеры можно привести, если спросят?

Comment: напишите ваш вариант ответа и попробуйте привести пример использования.

Comment: может быть, «явное указание» не «аргумента типа», а «типа аргумента»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так в книге написано (Философия Java)

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно вопрос по обобщенным типам (т.е. generic-ам).

Имеется ввиду, что есть два способа использовать обобщенные типы: явное указание аргумента типа и неявное указание аргумента типа.

#### Неявное указание

Во в большинстве случаев, компилятор сам может вывести тип и явное указание не нужно:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Optional<String> string = Optional.of("abc")
```

#### Явное указание

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Optional<String> string = Optional.<String>of("abc")
```

В этих простых примерах, явное указание аргумента обобщенного типа не нужно. Но в некоторых ситациях, может быть неоднозначность и компилятору нужна подсказка.